# How many fans does a MBP 13" late 2013 have?

Tags: macbook-pro, temperature

I was wondering how many fans a MBP 13" retina from late 2013 has, since I downloaded iStat Menus to check for internal temperatures because I thought my mbp was running fairly hot...  Now in the menu of the app, I can only see the speed of the RightSide fan, and I was wondering whether there is a leftside fan as well?

Can someone also specify the normal working range temperatures of this type of mbp, since I hope these temperatures are not really creating a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The late 2013 Macbook Pro 13" only has one fan. You can see here in [iFixit's teardown](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Late+2013+Teardown/18695#s53214).

Apple don't publish figures for normal working range temperature for their devices, and unfortunately you'll find many and varied opinions online. Apple do publish [a short guide](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1778) if you are concerned that your Macbook is overheating though.